# What is the purpose of Flux::sampleTimeout method in the project-reactor API?

Tags: reactive-programming, project-reactor

The Java docs say the following:

> Emit the last value from this Flux only if there were no new values emitted during the time window provided by a publisher for that particular last value.

However I found the above description confusing. I read in gitter chat that its similar to debounce in RxJava. Can someone please illustrate it with an example? I could not find this anywhere after doing a thorough search.

Comment: Thanks for editing it piet.

Comment: In particular I am trying to slow down emissions from Flux.interval, and am hoping Flux.sampleTimeout (RxJava's debounce equivalent ? ) might provide me with a way. For e.g. I notice with Flux.interval().map(time_varying_function), the 'flux.interval' events accumulate if the time_varying_function takes more time than the flux interval. However, I don't want those events to accumulate in case the consuming function is slow. But I *do* want the interval to be maintained if the consuming function is fast

Comment: Note that blocking in a `map` function is a big reactive programming code smell, unless you use `publishOn` to isolate that to a separate scheduler (and thus Thread).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your requirement. I'll describe the behavior of `sampleTimeout`, hopefully this will give you a better idea of whether or not this applies to your use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sampleTimeout` lets you associate a companion `Flux` `X'` to each incoming value `x` in the source. If `X'` completes before the next value is emitted in the source, then value `x` is emitted. If not, `x` is dropped.
The same processing is applied to subsequent values.

Think of it as splitting the original sequence into windows delimited by the start and completion of each companion flux. If two windows overlap, the value that triggered the first one is dropped.

On the other side, you have `sample(Duration)` which only deals with a single companion Flux. It splits the sequence into windows that are contiguous, at a regular time period, and drops all but the last element emitted during a particular window.

(edit): **about your use case**

If I understand correctly, it looks like you have a processing of varying length that you want to schedule periodically, but you also don't want to consider values for which processing takes more than one *period*?

If so, it sounds like you want to 1) isolate your processing in its own thread using `publishOn` and 2) simply need `sample(Duration)` for the second part of the requirement (the delay allocated to a task is not changing).

Something like this:

```
List<Long> passed =
      //regular scheduling:
    Flux.interval(Duration.ofMillis(200))
      //this is only to show that processing is indeed started regularly
    .elapsed()
      //this is to isolate the blocking processing
    .publishOn(Schedulers.elastic())
      //blocking processing itself
    .map(tuple -> {
        long l = tuple.getT2();
        int sleep = l % 2 == 0 || l % 5 == 0 ? 100 : 210;
        System.out.println(tuple.getT1() + "ms later - " + tuple.getT2() + ": sleeping for " + sleep + "ms");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(sleep);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return l;
    })
      //this is where we say "drop if too long"
    .sample(Duration.ofMillis(200))
      //the rest is to make it finite and print the processed values that passed
    .take(10)
    .collectList()
    .block();

System.out.println(passed);
```

Which outputs:

```
205ms later - 0: sleeping for 100ms
201ms later - 1: sleeping for 210ms
200ms later - 2: sleeping for 100ms
199ms later - 3: sleeping for 210ms
201ms later - 4: sleeping for 100ms
200ms later - 5: sleeping for 100ms
201ms later - 6: sleeping for 100ms
196ms later - 7: sleeping for 210ms
204ms later - 8: sleeping for 100ms
198ms later - 9: sleeping for 210ms
201ms later - 10: sleeping for 100ms
196ms later - 11: sleeping for 210ms
200ms later - 12: sleeping for 100ms
202ms later - 13: sleeping for 210ms
202ms later - 14: sleeping for 100ms
200ms later - 15: sleeping for 100ms
[0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 15]
```

So the blocking processing is triggered approximately every 200ms, and only values that where processed within 200ms are kept.

Comment: Thanks Simon. What I essentially want is Flux.interval to delay the next emission, if the time varying function ( which is compute intensive) takes longer than the flux interval. So, I do not want to drop the long computations,  For e.g. if the interval is 2 seconds, and first the compute takes 1.5 seconds, second compute takes 3 seconds, what I want is that the third emission from Flux.interval is delayed until the 2nd compute completes.I was thinking if there is a way to do this without back pressure.

Comment: I am using Flux.interval(duration, Schedulers.elastic()) , because in my use-case are multiple of these fluxes that are flatmapped together. I will try edit my post with some sample code.

Comment: I thought the above question should be a separate post with its own sample code and example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44317411/how-can-one-slow-down-emissions-form-flux-interval